# INNER JOIN trae datos duplicados o simplemente no trae nada si no consigue

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema, este query no esta funcionando bien. Si una de las alertas "al1, al2, al3" no sale en el WHERE, no trae ningún dato, y si quito al1, al2 o al3 del query del WHERE este se vuelve loco y trae los datos tres veces (Ese el número de alertas)

Lo que quiero es que se traiga toda la información si puede conseguirla, es decir si no consigue un alerta simplemente me traiga todos los datos que pudo conseguir ignorando esa condición

Ya intenté hacer Group By y no trae los datos bien tampoco, los trae en blanco

```
        SELECT cc.id_clasecliente,us.primer_nombre, us.primer_apellido, us.cedula, tu.numero_telefono AS movil,
        us.id_usuario, cc.asistio, cc.cancelacion_tardia, cc.web, cc.lista_espera, cc.id_clasefinal,
        cc.id_paquetecliente, pc.cantidad_clases, pc.fecha_vencimiento, pp.nombre_paquete, 
        al1.descripcion AS alerta_fisica, al2.descripcion AS alerta_personal, al3.descripcion AS alerta_salud
        FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc 
        INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us ON (cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc ON (cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp ON (pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete)
        INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu ON (cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario)
        INNER JOIN ec_alerta as al1 ON (cc.id_usuario = al1.id_usuario)
        INNER JOIN ec_alerta as al2 ON (cc.id_usuario = al2.id_usuario)
        INNER JOIN ec_alerta as al3 ON (cc.id_usuario = al3.id_usuario)
        WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = '" . $Id_clase . "'
        AND al1.id_tipoalerta = 1 
        AND al2.id_tipoalerta = 2
        AND al3.id_tipoalerta = 3
        AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 2
        ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
```

Comment: inner join es para datos que si o sí existen, si algún dato es nulo, se excluye de tu consulta. que resultado te da actualmente, y que resultado esperas? si enseñas algo así sería mucho más fácil de entender tu consulta

Comment: Lo que quiero es que si la condición "AND al3.id_tipoalerta = 3" no es satisfecha, que se traiga todos los datos que pueda ignorando esa condición. Quitando esa condicion y dejando INNER JOIN me da el resultado tres veces repetido si hay 3 alertas, y dos veces si hay dos, haciendo LEFT JOIN eso ocurre igualmente

Comment: Las alertas se relacionan solo con usuarios o también con paquetes? Diría que falta una condición en el INNER JOIN de `ec_alerta `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como dice un comentario, un `INNER JOIN` debe encontrar la condición de `JOIN` para que entregue resultados, por lo que deberías estar haciendo un `LEFT JOIN`. Luego se te multiplican los resultados porque estás haciendo el `JOIN` 3 veces **sin alguna condición que lo limite**.

Una alternativa para lograr lo que quieres es hacer el `LEFT JOIN` con una tabla que ya tenga el resultado unificado por `id_usuario` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT 
    cc.id_clasecliente,
    us.primer_nombre,
    us.primer_apellido,
    us.cedula,
    tu.numero_telefono AS movil,
    us.id_usuario,
    cc.asistio,
    cc.cancelacion_tardia,
    cc.web,
    cc.lista_espera,
    cc.id_clasefinal,
    cc.id_paquetecliente,
    pc.cantidad_clases,
    pc.fecha_vencimiento,
    pp.nombre_paquete,
    al.alerta_fisica,
    al.alerta_personal,
    al.alerta_salud
FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc
INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us
    ON (cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario)
LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc
    ON (cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente)
LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp
    ON (pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete)
INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu
    ON (cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id_usuario,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 1 THEN descripcion END) alerta_fisica,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 2 THEN descripcion END) alerta_personal,
                    MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 3 THEN descripcion END) alerta_salud
            FROM ec_alerta
            WHERE id_tipoalerta IN (1,2,3)
            GROUP BY id_usuario) al
    ON (cc.id_usuario = al.id_usuario)
WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = '" . $Id_clase . "'
AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 2
ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
```